# ng-pattern to Validate single digit number in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been searching this forum and others for angularjs pattern that will validate html input with ONLy single digit.

any number between 0-9 but should not accept any character including.

This is what i have done so far, but still does not work properly.

```
ng-pattern="/[0-9]{1}/"
ng-pattern="/[0-9{1}]/"
ng-pattern="/\d{1}/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regex for starting and stopping at that digit

```
ng-pattern="/\A\d\z/"
```

Or alternatively

```
ng-pattern="/^\d$/"
```

This will validate only 1 digit.

Answer (score 1):

this should match only one digit

```
 ng-pattern = /^[\d]$/;
```

Comment: Thank you, however it is not validating properly.

Comment: *"should match only one digit"*; what do you suspect the `+` is doing in your regex? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) tag?

```
<select ng-model="model.id" convert-to-number>
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```